# React Hooks Modify Array In Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I'm having trouble in React modifying values from an array with `useState` after rendering them to a table. Here's a simple example:

```
  //The hook
  const [awayAbilityAdjust, setAwayAbilityAdjust] = useState([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]);
```

Now, I render it to a table in Bootstrap with a `Form`:

```
                            <tr>
                              <td>Ability Adjust</td>
                              {awayAbilityAdjust.map((ability, index) => (
                                <td key={index}>                               
                                  <Form.Control
                                    size="sm"
                                    type="number"
                                    name="ability-input"
                                    step="0.1"
                                    value={ability}
                                    style={{
                                      width: "50px",
                                      backgroundColor: "#6d784b",
                                      color: "#ffff",
                                    }}
                                    min="0"
                                    max="10"
                                    onChange={updateHomeAbility(index)
                                    }
                                  />
                                  </td>
                              ))}
                            </tr>
```

Here is `updateHomeAbility`:

```
  const updateHomeAbility = (index) => (e) => {
    const updatedArray = [...homeAbilityAdjust];
    homeAbilityAdjust[index] = e.target.value;
    setHomeAbilityAdjust(updatedArray);
  };
```

However this doesn't change any of the values when I select the up and down buttons on the `Form`. How can I modify these values using `useState`?

Comment: Can you show the code of `updateHomeAbility`?

Comment: @RonB. Apologies, just added it, silly of me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're updating `homeAbilityAdjust` after copying it to `updatedArray`. You simply need to update `updatedArray` instead.

```js
const updateHomeAbility = (index) => (e) => {
  const updatedArray = [...homeAbilityAdjust];
  updatedArray[index] = e.target.value;
  setHomeAbilityAdjust(updatedArray);
};
```